# Is it possible to run a MIDP application under Android

Tags: android, midp

The Google Market offers an application purporting to run J2ME MIDP applications on the Nexus One.

I have tried this application but it only appears to run MIDP applications that are downloaded from particular web sites; it does not seem capable of picking up a MIDP application that is stored on the SD card in the phone.

I have suggested to the developers that they might like to add such functionality, but they have not been particularly responsive to my messages.

So I would like to build my own MIDP runner for Android and would like to see if I can find a pointer as to where to start, or even whether this is possible.

The MIDP application in question was supplied on CD along with a security camera system and permits remote viewing and remote control over the security system.

Clearly it wasn't built with the Android platform in mind. However, if it is possible somehow to run MIDP applications on Android (perhaps by creating some kind of sandbox environment for example) then I'd be quite keen to develop it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MicroEmulator](http://www.microemu.org/) is a Java implementation of Java ME. You could try porting this to Android. The UI part should be re-written, as MicroEmulator is based on Java SE components that aren't available in Android. Also hardware access won't be possible. Device vendors implement J2ME APIs (camera API for example) and bundle them with the core J2ME. This won't be easy for you to do. You will need to study the JSR specification and implement it in Android.

Comment: This was a very lengthy path to follow, hence the time it has taken me to reply to your suggestion...

IT WORKS!!! Thank you very much for your invaluable help. Most grateful.

Comment: Is it really working? That it is very impressive. What parts have you actually managed to make working?

Comment: The SecuViewer application connects over the internet, back through my router to the security camera system and its DVR. As far as I've tested it so far everything works. Examples: I can see all 4 camera images, I can select individual cameras and zoom and rotate its image, I can access the DVR and selectively replay recordings based on time/date/camera number. I've not yet tried altering the setup by remote control, but judging from the reactions of the playback menu system, which is working fine, remote setup changes should work just fine too. This gives me what I wanted.

Comment: The only issue is that of screen rotation. The manual rotation of the MIDP app clashes with the auto-rotation of the Nexus One so that if I get a full screen landscape image then I have to hold the N1 upright in portrait mode hence the image is sideways on to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [App Runner](http://www.netmite.com/android/) to port MIDP apps to Android.

Comment: I'd be a  little nervous... https://www.virustotal.com/#/url/7c822accf2f76c570f7030b3a2bc41e2a3a2f1542ffcc1be6fa7dedc18da693f/detection